# Configuring the right port on node-red Linux

Tags: linux

I'm trying to use the usb port on a pi similar device. Using Node-red , I need to tell which port should be activated.

[image]

So my problem is I don't get which port I'm connected to. when I go to `dev/` here is what I get :

```
    root@MYONE:/dev# ls
825000.etf       fb         kmsg          mem               mmcblk0p4           port   ptyp7   rtc0    tty13  tty24  tty35  tty46  tty57    tty96B1  ttyp5               urandom  vcsa1
826000.etr       fb0        log           memory_bandwidth  mmcblk0p5           ppp    ptyp8   shm     tty14  tty25  tty36  tty47  tty58    ttyMSM0  ttyp6               usbmon0  vcsa2
autofs           fd         loop-control  mmcblk0           mmcblk0p6           psaux  ptyp9   snd     tty15  tty26  tty37  tty48  tty59    ttyMSM1  ttyp7               usbmon1  vcsa3
block            full       loop0         mmcblk0boot0      mmcblk0p7           ptmx   ptypa   stderr  tty16  tty27  tty38  tty49  tty6     ttyS0    ttyp8               v4l      vcsa4
btrfs-control    fuse       loop1         mmcblk0boot1      mmcblk0p8           pts    ptypb   stdin   tty17  tty28  tty39  tty5   tty60    ttyS1    ttyp9               vcs      vcsa5
bus              hugepages  loop2         mmcblk0p1         mmcblk0p9           ptyp0  ptypc   stdout  tty18  tty29  tty4   tty50  tty61    ttyS2    ttypa               vcs1     vcsa6
char             i2c-0      loop3         mmcblk0p10        mmcblk0rpmb         ptyp1  ptypd   tty     tty19  tty3   tty40  tty51  tty62    ttyS3    ttypb               vcs2     vga_arbiter
console          i2c-2      loop4         mmcblk0p11        mqueue              ptyp2  ptype   tty0    tty2   tty30  tty41  tty52  tty63    ttyp0    ttypc               vcs3     video0
cpu_dma_latency  i2c-3      loop5         mmcblk0p12        net                 ptyp3  ptypf   tty1    tty20  tty31  tty42  tty53  tty7     ttyp1    ttypd               vcs4     video1
cuse             initctl    loop6         mmcblk0p13        network_latency     ptyp4  random  tty10   tty21  tty32  tty43  tty54  tty8     ttyp2    ttype               vcs5     watchdog
disk             input      loop7         mmcblk0p2         network_throughput  ptyp5  rfkill  tty11   tty22  tty33  tty44  tty55  tty9     ttyp3    ttypf               vcs6     watchdog0
dri              kmem       media0        mmcblk0p3         null                ptyp6  rtc     tty12   tty23  tty34  tty45  tty56  tty96B0  ttyp4    udev_network_queue  vcsa     zero
root@MYONE:/dev#
```

runing `dmesg` delivers the following:

```
[ 1027.106904] usb 1-1.3: new full-speed USB device number 8 using msm_hsusb_host
[ 1027.209734] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=16de, idProduct=0003
[ 1027.209807] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 1027.215965] usb 1-1.3: Product: USB - RS485 SL cable
[ 1027.222914] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: 
[ 1027.228243] usb 1-1.3: SerialNumber: 16440303
```

so my question is what should setup in the serial port in node red ?

thanks in advance !

Answer (score -1):

There probably isn't any. Linux doesn't appear to have a driver compatible with your USB device.

Comment: Thanks for replying . But I don't get your point ?